# Call insmod after make and rmmod after clean in Makefile

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

For the following simple makefile, is it possible to:

1. call insmod after make
2. call rmmod after clean

   ```
       obj-m+=hello.o

       all:
           make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
       clean:
           make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a dev, I would expect `make` to just produce a binary, and not do any other changes on my system. I would suggest you use a typical approach and do the install/rmmod/insmod/whatever via `make install`:

```
MODULE = trololo

...

install:
    rmmod $(MODULE)
    insmod $(MODULE).ko
```

And then you build:

```
make
```

And remove/install module:

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: That makes sense - that is what I went for in the end